How to let a player not moving through the another entity(2d)?
I am making a maze game with ursina but I cannot force the player to not go through wall. I have tried to add collider but it doesnt do anything, cuz i must check the collisions than give them codes to execute. I added raycast but it does the same thing as collider.Plss help me
Here is my code.
from ursina import *
from ursina import physics
class top_down_controller(Entity):
    def __init__(self, model, color, scale = 1, texture = None, collider = 'box', ignore=[], position=[0,0]):
        super().__init__(
            model = model,
            color = color,
            scale = scale,
            texture = texture,
            collider = collider,
            ignore = ignore,
            vleft = -0.1,
            vright = 0.1,
            vup = 0.1,
            vdown = -0.1,
            position= position
            )
    def update(self):
        
        self.x += held_keys['a'] * self.vleft
        self.x += held_keys["d"] * self.vright
        self.y += held_keys['w'] * self.vup
        self.y += held_keys['s'] * self.vdown
        above = raycast(self.world_position, self.up, 0.51, ignore=[self], debug = True)
        above_left = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(-0.5,0,0), self.up, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug = True)
        above_right = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0.5,0,0), self.up, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug = True)
        below = raycast(self.world_position, self.down, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug = True)
        below_left = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(-0.5,0,0), self.down, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug = True)
        below_right = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0.5,0,0), self.down, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug = True)
        left = raycast(self.world_position, self.left, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug = True)
        left_above = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0,0.5,0), self.left, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug = True)
        left_down = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0,-0.5,0), self.left, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug = True)
        right = raycast(self.world_position, self.right, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug=True)
        right_above = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0,0.5,0), self.right, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug = True)
        right_down = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0,-0.5,0), self.right, 0.51, ignore = [self], debug = True)
        if any((above.hit, above_left.hit, above_right.hit)):
            self.vup = 0
        elif any((left.hit, left_above.hit, left_down.hit)):
            self.vleft = 0
        elif any((right.hit, right_above.hit, right_down.hit)):
            self.vright = 0
        elif any((below_right.hit, below.hit, below_left.hit)):
            self.vdown = 0
app  = Ursina()
e1 = Entity(model = 'quad', color = color.green, collider = 'box')
e = top_down_controller(model = 'quad', color = color.blue, position = [2,2], ignore = [e1])

app.run()

